# How to get URLs from website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to get all URLs from this website:

https://www.bbvavivienda.com/es/buscador/venta/vivienda/todos/la-coruna/

There are a lot of links like `https://www.bbvavivienda.com/es/unidades/UV_n_UV00121705` inside but I'm not able to recover them with Selenium. Any idea how to do it?

I add more info about how I tried it. obviously... i'm starting with python, selenium, etc... thanks in advance:

```
**from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.bbvavivienda.com/es/buscador/venta/vivienda/todos/la-coruna/")
urls=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
print urls

links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('_self')
for link in links:
    print link.get_attribute("href")
driver.quit()**
```

Comment: *"tried"* **how**, exactly? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I add more info about how I tried it. obviously... i'm starting with python, selenium, etc... thanks Jonrsharpe for your help with my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code shall work. You are using the wrong identifier for the link.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get("https://www.bbvavivienda.com/es/buscador/venta/vivienda/todos/la-coruna/")
    urls=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print urls

    for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@target='_self']"):
        try:
            print link.get_attribute("href")
        except Exception:
            pass
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know python but normally in Java we can find all the elements in the webpage having tag as "a" for finding the links in the webpage. You can find the below code snippet useful.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        System.out.println(links.size());

        for (int i = 1; i<=links.size(); i=i+1)

        {

            System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());

        }
```

Comment: java solution for python problem?